# problem with status in jtwitter

Tags: java, status, jtwitter

My code with user id:

status = twitter.getStatus(userId);

working correctly, but stores the last status.

I want store a status that i choose, with this code:

status = twitter.getStatus(userId);

But not works for certain users and throws me this error:

Exception in thread "main" winterwell.jtwitter.TwitterException$E404: Not Found
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
{"error":"No status found with that ID.","request":"/1/statuses/show/112779914381492224.json?include_entities=1&"}
http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/show/112779914381492224.json?include_entities=1&
    at winterwell.jtwitter.URLConnectionHttpClient.processError(URLConnectionHttpClient.java:364)
    at winterwell.jtwitter.URLConnectionHttpClient.connect(URLConnectionHttpClient.java:149)
    at winterwell.jtwitter.URLConnectionHttpClient.getPage(URLConnectionHttpClient.java:201)
    at winterwell.jtwitter.Twitter.getStatus(Twitter.java:1384)
    at extractordecaracterísticasentwitter.Tracker.listLocation(Tracker.java:83)
    at extractordecaracterísticasentwitter.Tracker.extractorTweets(Tracker.java:35)
    at extractordecaracterísticasentwitter.Main.main(Main.java:45)
Java Result: 1

thanks for response and excuse me my english xD

Answer (score 0):

Probably the ID doesn't exist?

The ID you posted throws this

> {"error":"No status found with that
>   ID.","request":"/1/statuses/show/112779914381492224.json?include_entities=1&"}

Comment: I print tweetId and print well, therefore is not empty

Answer (score 0):

A 404 error (which is what you've got) means Twitter doesn't recognise the id number you've supplied.

This is because showById() expects the id of the *tweet*, whilst you're passing it a user-id. 
It's the wrong method for you (the use cases for showById are rare but valid).

Try `Twitter.getUserTimeline(Long userId)` instead.

Or you can use `twitter.users().show(userId)` to get info on the user, which includes their last tweet.